# Iterate through array in Javascript on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to iterate through an array, like so:

```
var locs = [
  ['Location 0', 50, 91], 
  ['Location 1', 50, 100]
];

for (i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
    $('#' + i).click(function(i) {
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(locs[i][1], locs[i][2]));
    })

}
```

But I get the unexpected identifier because of the way loops work in Javascript. I need it to iterate through the `locs` array.

How do I do this? So frustrated!

I tried the `return function` thing but it didn't work.

E.G.:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      $('#' + i).click(function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]));
          }
      )};
}
```

Comment: Are the ids actually numbers? I think that is invalid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be doing is indexing your clickable elements numerically where it would probably be better to give them all a class and maybe give them some `data-` attributes to indicate any further information rather than numerical id's. This has a number of benefits, first once you use an Id you should never use it again. `#1`, `#2` etc. would need to become something else if you wanted to use the same technique again in the same DOM structure. As well as this, what would happen if you pushed a new value to your `locs` array in the future and wanted to then bind an elements click event how would you achieve it?

Maybe a better type of solution would involve using delegated events and avoiding indexing by Id. So to index you can use the DOM structure itself, or apply a `data-` attribute.

example element

```
<a class="map-location" data-index="1">Location 1</a>
```

JS

```
var locs = [
    ['Location 0', 50, 91], 
    ['Location 1', 50, 100]
];

$(document).on('.map-location', 'click', function(event) {
    var self = $(this),
        index = self.data('index'), // Index by `data-index`
        selfIndex = self.parent().index(self); // Or index by DOM location

    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(locs[index][1], locs[index][2]));
});
```

No need to side step closures or using expensive `$.each` calls, also new locations can be pushed to the `locs` array at any time, as long as an element is created with the correct class and index to click on, it will have a bound event to pan to the marker.

Comment: *No need to side step closures or using expensive $.each calls* Yes, storing data like that avoids those pesky expensive function calls.... :)

Answer (score 0):

> But I get the unexpected identifier because of the way loops work in Javascript

It has nothing to do with the way loops work.

> I tried the `return function` thing but it didn't work.

Returning a function won't do anything. The return value must be a boolean from an event handler's function.

You've got the *closures* problem.

You're in luck 'cos you're using jQuery, and `$.each()` will side-step the closure problem.

```
$.each(locs, function(i) {
    $('#' + i).click(function(index) {
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(locs[i][1], locs[i][2]));
    });
});
```

What you should really understand is that inner function closed over `i`, and it holds a reference to it.

By the time that `click` handler is called, it will look up `i` in the scope chain and find the scope where it was defined. When it does, that `for` loop will have incremented it beyond a subscriptable array element.

Comment: Ya, don't read it enough :)

Comment: Yes, I tried the return function thing like the Google example because of the closures, but I must have done it wrong. I added my dysfunctional code with closures in mind.

Comment: @AAA Unfortunately, the code you tried won't do it. You can use an IIFE or `with() {}`, or just use jQuery's iterator.

Comment: Thanks, works well. Thanks for the vid on closures. I'll watch it.

Comment: Now for some reason, the code will update the infowindows but it won't go to the new location. It goes to the last location in the list.

Comment: Was going to accept your answer, but did not realize the closures video was not actually a closures video. Rude.

Comment: @AAA Rude because your assumption proved to be incorrect?

Comment: @alex Rude because the video you initially linked was some sarcastic thing that had to do with magnets. Also, a mod edited out your answer.

Comment: @AAA It was a meme that I decided to post for some stupid reason. Another contributor censored it, I edited it myself out of my answer.